# Using a collimating lens for beam interference

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics, lenses

If I have two beams of light which are incident on the same point of a collimating lens, will they emerge as a single beam and interfere? I've attached a drawing below:
[image: Collimating lens for beam inteference]

If not, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they will not emerge as a single beam.  See [Thin Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_lens) in Wikipedia for a better understanding of how a lens works.

Your arrangement will produce two beams which may or may not overlap downstream from the lens.  Where they do overlap, they will interfere *if* they are mutually conherent -- e.g., if both beams are derived from the same laser-- and if everything in the setup holds still.